# Using FragmentManager to always return to the same fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am developing an application which contains NavigationDrawer with multiple tabs, which calls to different fragments.

- Let's say I have fragments A, B, C.
- On the creation of the activity the fragment container is populated with fragment A.
- I want to somehow save a reference to this fragment that when I navigate to others fragment I will get back to fragment A through onBackPress().
- It is important that fragment A will not be destroyed.

I tried implementing that with `addToBackStack()` on the first transaction, but it only works when navigation to one other fragment:

```
A -> B -> onBackPress() -> A
```

But when I navigate to more it doesnt work properly:

```
A -> B -> C -> onBackPress() -> C
```

While the desired outcome is :

```
A -> B -> C -> onBackPress() -> A
```

I must be missing something and would appreciate some help with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override your onBackPressed().

Then use popBackstackImmediate with flag: POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

This will popup all the backstack entries till the tag supplied in popBackstackImmediate() is found. 
So in short, in onBackPressed use popBackstackImmediate and supply it with Tag for Fragment A and also with flag POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. it is expected behavior. you have to add the addToBackStack() before every transaction to get the fragment while backpress

your flow should be like this

A (addToBackStack())-> B-> C -> onBackPress() -> B ->onBackPress() -> A.

Comment: I did try that, but as you see with this solution after onBackPress() on fragment C, it returns to fragment B, not A.